# discord.js, bot isn't upddating the amount of guilds

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I just made a 'guilds' command, that is supposed to return the amount of guilds where the bot is.

This is my code:

```
module.exports = {
    name : 'guilds',
    description : 'Returns the amount of guilds where the bot is',

    execute(client, message, args) {
        message.channel.send(`I am currently on ${client.guilds.cache.size} guilds!`)
    }
}
```

I wanted to test it, so ran it and added my bot on one more guild, restart it, but it's still returning the same number. Do you know if there is a delay or something like that before updating the amount of guilds?

Or maybe I did something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A feature of `Discord.js V12` is `cache`. Cache means that as time passes, more data will be stored about guilds, or members. The critical point here is `time`.

Unfortunately this means that it is highly unlikely that your command will ever be fully accurate.

Learn about cache and the general update from v11 => v12 [here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#before-you-start)

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as correct by clicking the tick